# Оксфордская запятая в русском языке

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы, однородные-члены, или

> Лучшее время для чтения книг? Между делами, после обеда и ужина или перед сном.

Нужна ли запятая перед словом ***или***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Между делами, после обеда и ужина или перед сном.***

Необходимости в запятой перед ***или*** нет.

[Однородные члены предложения, соединенные неповторяющимися союзами](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=100) (справочник Розенталя):

> **4.** Перед неповторяющимися разделительными союзами ***или, либо*** между однородными членами предложения запятая не ставится: *Цветы лучше всего собирать **утром или под вечер*** (Пауст.).

«В русском языке оксфордской запятой или ее аналога не существует» ([Оксфордская запятая – правила использования](https://lingua-airlines.ru/articles/oksfordskaya-zapyataya-pravila-ispolzovaniya/)).
«*Оксфордская запятая* – это знак препинания, который в письменном английском языке ставится при перечислении однородных членов... В русском языке такой знак препинания не используется» ([Грамота.ру](http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA)).